# un "Repositorios de Codigo" y la "Herencia y Polimorfismo" puede ser lo mismo en cuanto a evolucion de un proyecto?

Tags: php, java, poo, patrones-de-diseño

Buen día, esta pregunta quizás sea un poco extraña, pero después de que ya se lleva tiempo en el desarrollo se empiezan a apreciar ciertas similitudes que benefician la evolución de un proyecto, no ignoro que GitHub me permita crear backups y mantenerme un histórico y comparaciones de los cambios realizados, pero hablando mas a detalle, en cuanto a versionamiento y evolución de código se refiere; podemos comparar las "branch" (ramas) de GitHub, con la capacidad que tiene la POO de proveer polimorfismo, interface y patrones de diseño (PDD) como el "Strategy"? Dejando también a un lado el tema de las "dependencias, cohesión, acoplamiento, etc..." (en lo que normalmente GitHub nos retornaría solo el código funcional necesario).

Esta pregunta la inclino mas hacia la POO y PDD, es decir: podríamos en cuanto a evolución de un código se refiere, confiar meramente en clases, interface y PDD para solventar cualquier cambio que nos pida un cliente, sin que esto afecte significativamente el rendimiento de una aplicación? O es meramente necesario repositorios de código como GitHub, para que el proyecto sea mantenible a largo plazo, aun cuando eso implicara de alguna forma descartar todo código que no sirva para los procesos actuales del modelo de negocio que rige al proyecto?

Lo pregunto porque he visto que Librerias como el JDK de Java tienen un tema de evolución de código muy bien elaborado, y si bien con el tiempo algunas funciones son obsoletas para los nuevos métodos que ellos **recomiendan** utilizar, no los quitan del JDK porque pertenecen a una capa de bajo nivel de sus objetos y también pueden ser usados para crear nuevas implementaciones de objetos nuevos con rutas distintas de evolución.

...Entonces:

- Se puede usar la POO y los PDD para hacer evolucionar un código, sin descartar códigos previamente implementados, en favor de su posible reutilizacion? (De esta forma podría cumplir los requerimientos de cambio que me soliciten, admitiría cambios de parte de otros desarrolladores y no descartaríamos código estable, que se ha usado en otras ocasiones y pueden servir para proyectos alternativos derivados del mismo propósito inicial).

Comment: No veo relación entre los terminos. Por supuesto que una buena programación te permitirá actualizar y mejorar tu aplicación con el paso del tiempo. Pero eso no significa que no sea bueno guardar las diferencias entre cada iteración de desarrollo

Comment: No lo digo por oponerme a GitHub, sino mas bien, por saber si tantas herencias, intefaces y clases abstractas no afectaran el rendimiento de la aplicacion de alguna forma? Y ademas tambien queria saber si existe una forma organizada de evolucionar en el codigo con solo POO y PDD sin necesidad de borrar, ni refactorizar clases...

Comment: refactorizar va a ser una tarea muy normal en cualquier tipo de desarrollo. Si acaso, puedes aplicar patrones de diseño, que ayudaran en tu proceso de "evitar borrar". Pero es muy posible que en un futuro, por requisitos de tu aplicacion/negocio, debas cambiar/borrar codigo...